# Будет ли размещаться весь файл в оперативной память при использовании следующей конструкции

Tags: python

Меня интересует будет ли файл загружаться полностью в оперативную память при использовании моей конструкции, которая должна выводить случайную строку из файла. Может есть способ лучше реализовать это? И как можно выгружать этот файл из оперативной памяти (в этом же коде) после вывода строки?

```
from random import randint
n1 = randint(0,9)
with open('lines.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()[n1]
    print(lines)
```

Comment: а как связан с заданными двумя вопросами модуль random?

Comment: Да, будет. Временно. "Выгрузится" сам когда сборщик мусора пройдётся и увидит, что данные больше не используются.

Comment: @aleksandr barakin Никак. я просто написал что должна делать эта программа. Возможно, вопрос задан немного не корректно. Меня интересует будет ли в оперативной памяти целый файл или только выбранная случайная строка. А также есть ли модули или функции помогающие выгрузить из оперативной памяти этот файлу (или эту строку).

Comment: Читайте построчно, и тогда в памяти будет одна строка ( ну почти)

Comment: @Keker, [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Вызов `file.readlines()` - прочитает в память все строки файла. После этого вызова эти данные не используются и поэтому при следующем вызове сборщик мусора освободит эту область памяти.

В данном случае можно воспользоваться [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
from itertools import islice

with open('lines.txt', 'r') as file:
    line = list(islice(file, n1, n1+1))[0]
```